# What additional actions should an ethical Bitcoin-related business take with each transaction?

Tags: privacy, legal, taxes, aml, know-your-customer

I'm considering starting an ethical business for users that accepts Bitcoin as a payment.  My intent is to abide by all laws and interpret them in an appropriate manner.

> My intent is to abide by the "spirit" of existing tax and state law.  What special actions should I take when accepting Bitcoin as payment for my services?

Some things I've considered include:

- Detailed logging of the transaction (IP addresses, shipping address)
- Voluntarily pay taxes on income, international fees (if any apply)
- Enhanced identity validation of each person involved in the transaction
- Adherence to data privacy laws (EU PII laws, HIPAA, etc)
- Co-operation with federal authorities with regard to legal subpoenas (etc)

Comment: Don't forget that you are competing against every other business. If a competitor has lower cost because these "special actions" aren't necessary, you will operate at a competitive disadvantage.

But go ahead, knock yourself out!